# Как проверить существует ли сайт через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Пользователь вводит название сайта и программа должна самостоятельно проверить что это за сайт:
Допустим пользователь вводит: google
Программа должна проверить что это за сайт: google.com или google.ru и так далее...
И если этот сайт существует, то открыть его

Comment: Пройтись циклом по [доменам верхнего уровня](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) и по каждому отправить DNS или HTTP запрос

Comment: А чем отправлять то? может есть какая-то библиотека?

Comment: А если существуют разные сайты с одинаковым именем, отличающиеся только доменами верхнего уровня? Например, abc.ru и abc.com - два ВООБЩЕ разных сайта, принадлежащие абсолютно разным организациям, и имеющие абсолютно разную тематику. Что должна программа открыть пользователю, если он введёт "abc" ?

Comment: Да, есть библиотека `requests` - она достаточно проста для подобных операций

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пока никто из тех кто действительно знает не ответил, я вот так это вижу исходя из вопроса, такой набросок:

```
import requests

domens = ['.ru', '.com', '.рф', '.net', '.org', '.ru.net', '.pro', '.ua', ]


def check_site(site_name):
    for domen in domens:
        site = f'https://www.{site_name}{domen}'
        try:
            response = requests.get(site)
            print(f'На сайт "{site}" можно перейти')
        except:
            print(f'Сайт "{site}" не открывается')


check_site('google')
```

Результат:

```
На сайт "https://www.google.ru" можно перейти
На сайт "https://www.google.com" можно перейти
Сайт "https://www.google.рф" не открывается
На сайт "https://www.google.net" можно перейти
На сайт "https://www.google.org" можно перейти
Сайт "https://www.google.ru.net" не открывается
Сайт "https://www.google.pro " не открывается
На сайт "https://www.google.ua" можно перейти
```